# The internal of numpy ndarray's attributes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Numpy v1.19. I found that `id` of some of the `ndarray` attributes, such as `shape` and `T`, vary every time I access them.

For example, `id(a.T)` and `id(a.shape)` results in different values in the code below.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(range(12)).reshape(3, 4)
>>> id(a.T)
4510863728
>>> id(a.T)
4537092976
>>> id(a.T)
4514908240
>>> id(a.shape)
4542374664
>>> id(a.shape)
4542475656
>>> id(a.shape)
4542515336
```

I don't understand this, because if you define a class which has a `ndarray` or `tuple` as its attribute, the `id` will never change. For example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, tuple):
...         self.tuple = tuple
...
>>> a = A((0, 1, 2))
>>> id(a.tuple)
4339273800
>>> id(a.tuple)
4339273800
>>> id(a.tuple)
4339273800
```

Why those things happen to `ndarray.shape` and `ndarray.T`, and not to `A.tuple`?

P.S. I've noticed those things can happen if they are defined as `@property`. Are they?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `property`, but these attributes use the C-level equivalent, a [getset descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GetSetDescriptorType). Getset descriptors run arbitrary code on attribute access, just like properties, and the getset descriptors for these attributes construct new objects.